# Outlook Calendar sync to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I have an existing calendar in Outlook, which I would like to show in SharePoint.  I know I can connect a SharePoint calendar to Outlook, but I want to do it the other way around.  Outlook Calendar has all meetings and invites already, so I need to share this calendar to SharePoint.  How would I do that?

Comment: Which SharePoint-Version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't establish Outlook->SharePoint calendar sync, only the vice versa is possible.

However, a one (and IMHO proper) way to do this would be the following:

1. Move all the items from the Outlook calendar to the SharePoint calendar
2. Make SharePoint calendar the main one
3. Suggest users to import the SharePoint calendar into their Outlook clients

Comment: Thank you Evictorov - unfortunately the outlook calendar invites have already been send out to the board of directors - they do not want to recreate the calendar again and re-invite the board. :-( But your solution would have helped a lot.